# How Can I have my old programs?

Tags: partitioning

I tried, to install another ubuntu on secend partition so I want to have my old programs which they were on sda2 in new ununtu.

Comment: I'm not completely sure what you want, but you can share data partitions between two releases of Ubuntu though it's not always a good idea (if the releases vary, the data files maybe modified by one version in a way the other version of the same software program can misinterpret or not handle; I discovered this first hand; new feature in `evolution` made mail invisible to older release).  Applications are stored though in specific places, so each release will need it's own applications stored (*deb* packages anyway; maybe less critical for some containerized alternatives).

Comment: Prorams are enerally not transferable from one Ubuntu version to another except through an upgrade. They must be manually reinstalled. The home directory can be copied from one version of Ubuntu to another using Rsync or Grsync.